# pyspark rdd of csv to data frame with large number of columns dynamically

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have an existing rdd which consists of a single column of text with many (20k+) comma separated values.

How can I convert this to a data frame without specifying every column literally?

```
# split into columns
split_rdd = input_rdd.map(lambda l: l.split(","))
# convert to Row types 
rows_rdd = split_rdd.map(lambda p: Row(
   field_1=p[0], 
   field_2=p[1],
   field_3 = float(p[2]),
   field_4 = float(p[3])
))
df = spark.createDataFrame(rows_rdd)
```

How can I dynamically create the

> field_1=p[0],

dict?

For example

```
row_dict = dict(
   field_1=p[0], 
   field_2=p[1],
   field_3 = float(p[2]),
   field_4 = float(p[3])
)
```

is invalid syntax since the 'p[0]' needs to be quoted, but then it is a literal and doesn't get evaluated in the lambda function.

This is a large enough dataset that I need to avoid writing out the rdd and reading it back into a dataframe for performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using dictionary comprehension in your creation of the row instance:

```
df = split_rdd\
            .map(lambda p: {'field_%s' % index : val 
                             for (index, val) in enumerate(p)})\
            .map(lambda p: Row(**p))\
            .toDF()
```

This is first mapping the list column values array from `split_rdd` into a dictionary with dynamically generated `field_N` keys mapped to respective values. These dictionaries are then used in the creation of `Row` instances.

Comment: I was trying to use dict comprehension with ** but didn't see that I needed two maps to make it go.  Perfect!